# ¿Guardar valores de forma persistente en variables entre cargas de una misma página o en diferentes páginas en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, cache

Como guardar variables de forma global no es recomendable, como podría guardar valores en variables que se mantengan persistentemente al cargar varias veces una misma págiina o al ir a otras páginas y que la variable no sea borrada?

Por ejemplo, guardo dentro de un módulo una variable privada donde me interesa guardar o cachear algunos valores para tenerlos luego disponibles.

```
            const mod = (function() {

                let privada = "foo";

                return {
                    v: "hola",
                    f: () => {
                        console.log(mod.v);
                        console.log(privada);
                        v = "mundo";
                        privada = "bar";
                    }
                };

            }());

            mod.f();
```

Es un ejemplo bastante simple pero al volver a cargar la página la variable se ha vuelto a inicializar.

Cual sería la mejor manera de poder guardar variables de forma a ser posible privada y persistente? Si no puede hacerse de manera privada al menos que me deje guardarlo de forma persistente?

Comment: Podiras usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) o [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Por favor usa la sección de respuestas para recomendar una solución, estaría muy bien que incluyeras un ejemplo con tu recomendación. La sección de comentarios no es muy útil ni fue diseñada para ese propósito. [más información sobre comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Julian, yo vote cerrar esta pregunta porque se base en opiniones. Solo deje links para que OP sepa que existen varias opciones y el tome su propia decisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando Local Storage, seria algo así:

NOTA: No funciona aquí... en este editor pero puedes probar este [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/43df4v4f/)

```js
/*Igualando la variable con el valor de la caja de texto y guardándola en localStorage*/
var key = "Nombre";
//localStorage["Nombre"] = "algo";
localStorage.setItem(key, "algo");
$("#mostrar").click(function(){
  //Las dos formas son validas, es mas recomendable la segunda
  //$("#info").text(localStorage["Nombre"]);//Version 1
  $("#info").text(localStorage.getItem(key));//Version 2
  
localStorage.setItem(key, data);
});

$("#save").click(function(){
  //localStorage["Nombre"] = $("#nombre").val();//Version 1
  localStorage.setItem(key, data);//Version 2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nombre"/>

<br>
<button id="save">Guardar Local Storage</button>

<br>
<br>
<button id="mostrar">Consultar Local Storage</button>
<br>
<div id="info"></div>
```

**Ejemplo con cookies:**

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var key = "Nombre";

$("#save").click(function(){
  var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
  setCookie(key,nombre,1);//Cookie durará 1 dia
});


$("#mostrar").click(function(){
  $("#nombre").val(getCookie(key));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nombre"/>

<br>
<button id="save">Guardar Cookie</button>

<br>
<br>
<button id="mostrar">Consultar Cookie</button>
<br>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Ver ejemplo [Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/pz9oqf34/)

Comment: En realidad debiese usar localStorage.setItem y localStorage.getItem. Me parece que acceder o setear las propiedades en forma directa es posible pero no recomendado.

Comment: ¿Porqué no pones la respuesta con el ejemplo que tu dices? en realidad no se mucho sobre localStorage... solo se que existe.  @amenadiel

Comment: Porque tu respuesta es correcta y resuelve la duda del usuario. Sólo no se apega al encapsulamiento recomendado en la documentación. [Mira esta pregunta de StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092715/localstorage-use-getitem-setitem-functions-or-access-object-directly)

Comment: Ok, puedes complementar mi respuesta entonces :-), tiene sentido Gracias por el aporte (Y)

Comment: Me sale un mensaje de error en la ejecución aquí mismo con la aplicación de Stack Overflow.


{
  "message": "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 26,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: @Lorthas creo que esto depende el Explorador que estés utilizando U_U, si no te funciona esta forma, tendrías que usar cookies